# TimeZone issue in my java code

Tags: java, date, datetime

I am trying to get the localtimezone using TimeZone.getDefault(), server is running in CST Timezone but whenever i execute the below piece of code, i am getting the output as "Wed Nov 5, 2014 03:52:22 PM GMT" but i need the timezone in CST. Is there something wrong with my code?

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");

Date dtTimeStamp = dateFormat.parse((String) map.get("TimeStamps")); 

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a zzz");

TimeZone tzDefault = TimeZone.getDefault();

dateFormat2.setTimeZone(tzDefault);

dateFormat2.format(dtTimeStamp);
```

Comment: In the future, please [format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make it more readable.

Comment: The code does not make any output, so it is not obvious what you're asking about here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [TimeZone.getDefault() JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

> Typically, you get a TimeZone using getDefault which creates a TimeZone based on the time zone where the program is running.

So, You must explicitly provide the TimeZone you want

```
TimeZone tzDefault = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
```

Comment: Currently the program is running on the server whose timezone is CST, but my code is returning the GMT. This is the problem.

Comment: Humm, What's your serveur os and the JRE version?

Comment: OS: Win Server 2008  jre: 1.5.0_05

Answer (score 0):

If `TimeZone.getDefault()` doesn't return CST, then you server is not in CST timzone, or is not configured as such.

The [value returned from](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--) `TimeZone.getDefault()` is determined by:

> - Use the user.timezone property value as the default time zone ID if    it's available.
> - Detect the platform time zone ID. The source of the platform time    zone and ID mapping may vary with implementation.
> - Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is    unknown.

You can check your server configuration, or you can explicitly get the CST time zone:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");
```